# Found ranking position for user

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I have a these tables

**USERS**

```
+----------+---------------+
| id_users |   usr_email   |
+----------+---------------+
| 1        | a@domain.com  |
| 2        | b@domain.com  |
| 3        | c@domain.com  |
| 4        | d@domain.com  |
| 5        | e@domain.com  |
+----------+---------------+
```

**RANKING**

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+
| id_ranking  | id_users  |  points  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 50          | 1         | 27       | //3rd
| 51          | 2         | 55       | //1st
| 52          | 3         | 9        | //5th
| 53          | 4         | 14       | //4th
| 54          | 5         | 38       | //2nd
+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

I would like to retireve user's data along with it's ranking position, filtering by e-mail. So for example if I want info for mail **c@domain.com** I should get

```
+----------+--------|---------------+
| id_users | points | rank_position |
+----------+--------|---------------+
| 3        | 9      | 5             |
+----------+--------|---------------+
```

I've found this piece of query that returns the ranking position

```
SELECT x.id_users, x.position
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id_ranking, t1.id_users, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position
    FROM ranking t1
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r ORDER BY t1.points desc
) x
WHERE x.id_users = 3
```

But I can't manage to use it in my old query

```
select u.*, r.points
from users u 
left join ranking r on r.id_users = u.id_users
where u.usr_email = 'c@domain.com'
```

My attemp

```
select u.*, r.points, p.*
from users u 
left join ranking r on r.id_users = u.id_users,

(SELECT x.id_users, x.position
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id_ranking, t1.id_users, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position
    FROM ranking t1
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r ORDER BY t1.points desc
) x
 WHERE x.id_users = u.id_users) p

where u.usr_email = 'c@domain.com'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `join` condition.  But also, the outer join to `ranking` is not necessary.  You can "remember" the points in the subquery:

```
select u.*, r.points, r.position
from users u left join
     (select r.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position
      from ranking r CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
      order by r.points desc
     ) r
     ON r.id_users = u.id_users
where u.usr_email = 'c@domain.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.id_users,
       r.points,
       count(ifnull(r2.id_users, 0)) + 1 as rank_position
  from users u
  join ranking r
    on u.id_users = r.id_users
  left join ranking r2
    on r2.points > r.points
 where u.usr_email = 'c@domain.com'
 group by u.id_users, r.points
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1444e8/1/0

Rather than a variable this counts the number of users who have more points than the given user, and then adds one. This is an equivalent way of calculating their rank, in terms of number of points.